# After reading a file I have IO [Char], but I need [IO Char]

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a file `number.txt` which contains a large number and I read it into an `IO String` like this:

```hs
readNumber = readFile "number.txt" >>= return
```

In another function I want to create a list of `Int`s, one Int for each digit…

Lets assume the content of `number.txt` is:

```
1234567890
```

Then I want my function to return `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`.

I tried severall versions with `map`, `mapM(_)`, `liftM`, and, and, and, but I got several error messages everytime, which I was able to reduce to

```
Couldn't match expected type `[m0 Char]'
            with actual type `IO String'
```

The last version I have on disk is the following:

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

main = intify >>= putStrLn . show

readNumber = readFile "number.txt" >>= return

intify = mapM (liftM digitToInt) readNumber
```

So, as far as I understand the error, I need some function that takes `IO [a]` and returns `[IO a]`, but I was not able to find such thing with hoogle… Only the other way round seemes to exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got some things mixed up:

```
readNumber = readFile "number.txt" >>= return
```

the return is unecessary, just leave it out.

Here is a working version:

```
module Main where

import Data.Char (digitToInt)

main :: IO ()
main = intify >>= print

readNumber :: IO String
readNumber = readFile "number.txt"

intify :: IO [Int]
intify = fmap (map digitToInt) readNumber
```

Comment: As to why `>>= return` is superfluent: that very identity is one of the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other great answers here, it's nice to talk about how to *read* `[IO Char]` versus `IO [Char]`. In particular, you'd call `[IO Char]` "an (immediate) list of (deferred) `IO` actions which produce `Char`s" and `IO [Char]` "a (deferred) `IO` action producing a list of `Char`s".

The important part is the location of "deferred" above---the major difference between a type `IO a` and a type `a` is that the former is best thought of as a set of instructions to be executed at runtime which eventually produce an `a`... while the latter is just that very `a`.

This phase distinction is key to understanding how `IO` values work. It's also worth noting that it can be very fluid within a program---functions like `fmap` or `(>>=)` allow us to peek behind the phase distinction. As an example, consider the following function

```
foo :: IO Int         -- <-- our final result is an `IO` action
foo = fmap f getChar where  -- <-- up here getChar is an `IO Char`, not a real one
  f :: Char -> Int
  f = Data.Char.ord   -- <-- inside here we have a "real" `Char`
```

Here we build a deferred action (`foo`) by modifying a deferred action (`getChar`) by using a function which views a world that only comes into existence after our deferred `IO` action has run.

---

So let's tie this knot and get back to the question at hand. Why can't you turn an `IO [Char]` into an `[IO Char]` (in any meaningful way)? Well, if you're looking at a piece of code which has access to `IO [Char]` then the first thing you're going to want to do is sneak inside of that `IO` action

```
floob = do chars <- (getChars :: IO [Char])
           ...
```

where in the part left as `...` we have access to `chars :: [Char]` because we've "stepped into" the `IO` action `getChars`. This means that by this point we've must have already run whatever runtime actions are required to generate that list of characters. We've let the cat out of the monad and we can't get it back in (in any meaningful way) since we can't go back and "unread" each individual character.

(Note: I keep saying "in any meaningful way" because we absolutely can put cats back into monads using `return`, but this won't let us go back in time and have never let them out in the first place. That ship has sailed.)

So how do we get a type `[IO Char]`? Well, we have to know (without running any `IO`) what kind of `IO` operations we'd like to do. For instance, we could write the following

```
replicate 10 getChar :: [IO Char]
```

and immediately do something like

```
take 5 (replicate 10 getChar)
```

without ever running an `IO` action---our list structure is immediately available and not deferred until the runtime has a chance to get to it. But note that we must know exactly the structure of the `IO` actions we'd like to perform in order to create a type `[IO Char]`. That said, we could use yet another level of `IO` to peek at the real world in order to determine the parameters of our action

```
do len <- (figureOutLengthOfReadWithoutActuallyReading :: IO Int)
   return $ replicate len getChar
```

and this fragment has type `IO [IO Char]`. To run it we have to step through `IO` *twice*, we have to let the runtime perform *two* `IO` actions, first to determine the length and then second to actually act on our list of `IO Char` actions.

```
sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
```

The above function, `sequence`, is a common way to execute some structure containing a, well, sequence of `IO` actions. We can use that to do our two-phase read

```
twoPhase :: IO [Char]
twoPhase = do len <- (figureOutLengthOfReadWithoutActuallyReading :: IO Int)
              putStrLn ("About to read " ++ show len ++ " characters")
              sequence (replicate len getChar)

>>> twoPhase
Determining length of read
About to read 22 characters
let me write 22 charac"let me write 22 charac"
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a function can't exists, because you would be able to evaluate the length of the list without ever invoking any `IO`.

What is possible is this:

```
imbue' :: IO [a] -> IO [IO a]
imbue' = fmap $ map return
```

Which of course generalises to

```
imbue :: (Functor f, Monad m) => m (f a) -> m (f (m a))
imbue = liftM $ fmap return
```

You can then do, say,

```
quun :: IO [Char]
bar :: [IO Char] -> IO Y

main = do
   actsList <- imbue quun
   y <- bar actsLists
   ...
```

Only, the whole thing about using `[IO Char]` is pointless: it's completely equivalent to the much more straightforward way of working only with lists of "pure values", only using the `IO` monad "outside"; how to do that is shown in Markus's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need many different helper functions? Because you may write just

```
main = do
    file <- readFile "number.txt"
    let digits = map digitToInt file
    print digits
```

or, if you really need to separate them, try to minimize the amount of `IO` signatures:

```
readNumber = readFile "number.txt" --Will be IO String

intify = map digitToInt --Will be String -> [Int], not IO

main = readNumber >>= print . intify
```